# Read Windows Registry value into array

Tags: vbscript, windows-7

I have to read **Windows Registry value** into array in VBA. Value has type `REG_MULTI_SZ`.

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."
Set objReg = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _ 
             strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Authentication Packages"
strValueName = "Sources"
Return = objReg.GetMultiStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, _
         strValueName, arrValues)
If (Return = 0) And (Err.Number = 0) Then   
    'Treat the multistring value as a collection of strings 
    'separated by spaces and output
    For Each strValue In arrValues
        WScript.Echo  strValue
    Next
Else
    WScript.Echo "GetMultiStringValue failed. Error = " & Err.Number
End If
```

[image]

It gives an error with number 0 and no description. Any clue?

Comment: Define "no joy". Do you get an error? Unwanted output? No output at all? What is the actual tpye of `arrValues`? (`WScript.Echo TypeName(arrValues)`)

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Hi! Please take a look at the updated question. Thank you!

Comment: You depend on 2 conditions. If `Err.Number` is 0 but you still get to the `Else` branch it means that `Return` is not 0, so check that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your screenshot your key is "Authentication Packages", not "Sources".

Change this:

```
strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Authentication Packages"
strValueName = "Sources"
```

into this:

```
strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa"
strValueName = "Authentication Packages"
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple error. The working code is here.

```
const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

strComputer = "."

Set objReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\"& strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
strKeyPath = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa"
strValueName = "Authentication Packages"

Return = objReg.GetMultiStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath, strValueName,arrValues)
 WScript.Echo  "GetMultiStringValue. Return = " & Return

    If (Return = 0) And (Err.Number = 0) Then   
' Treat the multistring value as a collection of strings 
'    separated by spaces and output
    For Each strValue In arrValues
    WScript.Echo  strValue
Next
Else
    Wscript.Echo "GetMultiStringValue failed. Error = " & Err.Number
End If
```